# C# WPF - Two state button issues. (Click event with touchscreen)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, touch

I have a problem with the buttons in WPF.
I'm developing a GUI which has a lot of pages and relative buttons (>50).
The GUI is supposed to be used with a touch screen display so every button has only two graphic state pressed and normal (there is no a hovered state), just like any button in a smartphone app.
Currently, I'm using this solution here:

Resource File

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="flatButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In one of the page

```
<Button 
    Uid=".../image_up.png" 
    Tag=".../image_down.png" 
    Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" 
    TouchLeave="buttonImageUp"  
    TouchDown="buttonImageDown" 
    Click="clickEvent" 
    ClickMode="Press"
    >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource=".../image_up.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Inside the related C# file

```
private void buttonImageDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.Content = new Image { 
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(button.Tag + "")), 
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, 
        Stretch = Stretch.Uniform 
    };
}

private void buttonImageUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.Content = new Image { 
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(button.Uid)), 
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, 
        Stretch = Stretch.Uniform 
    };
}
```

This implementatin has many issue:

- I can't use Uid and Tag
- Slow response because it has to run a C# function 2 time per touch
- I have to copy the C# function every time i need to use a button in a new page
- But the real issue is that i don't know why some time the clickEvent wont fire up when a button is pressed, and on some computer the clickEvent work only for the first 3~5 times than only touchDonw and touchLeave are working...

(I'm using .NET 4.6.1 but same behaviour with 4.5.2 and 4.7)

I think is possible to eliminate the C# component and change the image(source) of the button just with XAML, but I looking for a while and I can find nothing.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate [ToggleButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You can't do this with a Style trigger to set the image? What's the problem with Uid and Tag?

Comment: @icebat yes, but it is not very efficient to use C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="flatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <!-- Setters to style disabled state -->
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <!-- Setters to style pressed state -->
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You have to apply your own styling and there is a possiblity that you will have to change IsPressed to touch related propeties, but this should do the trick. No need for any custom logic in the C# code.

Comment: I try with this:
`c  <Setter.Value>
                                        <Button>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/file/Icons/Disc icon up.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                        </Button>
                                    </Setter.Value>`
`
It's not working with the mouse and there isn't anything like "IsTouchDown" or "IsTouchedLeave".
And also in such way I have to create a style for every button.

Comment: I have not developed any app on touch screens, but I think IsPressed is enough in this case, since touching Button is pressing it. I don't really get how you used my example, but please keep in mind that while setting template, ControlTemplate tag IS mandatory. Can you edit your question and paste formatted code to show how did you implemented my solution?
Also you don't have to create style for every Button. Just create it in your Application.Resources or other resource dictionary and use it just like you did before.